# How to stop userform from loading?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a userform. Before it loads i want to check some conditions. If those conditions are not met i do not want my form to load.

I tried to put userform1.hide in initialization event after error message box but form still loads.

how can i prevent it from loading.

Comment: Show us the code that's invoking the form, and what code-behind you've got for the form: give us a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Write codes on `UserForm_Activate()` event.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If Range("A1") = "" Then
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Adjust condition as your requirements.